# Reproduzir audio enquanto carrega

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Olá. Quando usamos o elemento `<audio>` ele só reproduz quando for carregado 100%. Queria ter ideia de como fazer para que ele reproduza enquanto ainda carrega, pra evitar a demora.
Podem me dar alguma informação?

Comment: se usar o atributo `preload=auto` o audio é carregado no arranque da página

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o elemento `<embed>`, que possui outras propriedades, seria algo como:

```html
<embed 
  src="/music/good_enough.mp3"
  loop="false"
  autostart="true">
```

Você pode chegar a referência [aqui](https://www.quackit.com/html/html_music_code.cfm).